# Fill up the list class object through a function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've created a class for List and by creating an object the constructor should call the function inside it and recursively go through all the database (H_Table/Table) and return List with all hierarchy structure in it.

How to do it, so, it'd go through all the elements and not just rewriting the same one when going through foreach and if/else statements?

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using Tree_List.Models;
    using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Tree_List.Controllers
{
    public class ListController : Controller
    {
        // GET: List
        private Models.ListDBEntities1 db_connection = new Models.ListDBEntities1();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var Hierarchy = db_connection.H_Table;
            Element Item = new Element(Hierarchy, null);
            return View(Item);
        }


    }

    public partial class Element
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }
        public List<Element> CHILDS { get; set; }

        public Element(DbSet<H_Table> Table, int? ParentID)
        {
            PopulateList(Table, ParentID);
        }

        public List<Element> PopulateList (DbSet<H_Table> Table, int? ParentI)
        {
            List<Element> temp = new List<Element>();
            foreach (var root in Table)
            {
                if (root.PARENT_ID == null)
                {
                    ID = root.ID;
                    NAME = root.NAME;
                    foreach (var child in Table)
                    {
                        if (child.PARENT_ID == ID)
                        {
                            ID = child.ID;
                            NAME = child.NAME;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return temp;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this. it will return list of all element

```
List<Element> = db_connection.H_Table.Select(s=>new Element {
ID = s.ID,
NAME =s.NAME
}).ToList();
```